# please tell why control is not going to the pst.setString(1, userName); and next line control directly going to the elseif (more= true) 3rd line

Tags: java

See the control after the prepared statement going to the `else if(more){}` block

```
try{
    //System.out.println("iam in first line");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,passsword);
    String userName = ex.getUserName();
    String password = ex.getPassword();
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from employee where username = ? and password = ? "); `after this line control is not there`
    pst.setString(1, userName);
    pst.setString(2, password);
    int k = pst.executeUpdate();
    boolean  more;
    if(k > 0)
    {
        //boolean  more = rs.next();
        more = true;
    }
    else {
        more = false;
    }
    if(!more)
    {
        System.out.println("you are not a registered user!");
        ex.setValid(false);
    }
    else if(more)
    {
        String firstName = rs.getString("name");
        String lastName = rs.getString("rollnumber");

        System.out.println("Welcome " + firstName); `control coming here`
        ex.setFirstName(firstName);
        ex.setLastName(lastName);
        ex.setValid(true);
    }

}
catch(Exception tex)
{
    tex.printStackTrace();
    //System.out.println("hey there is an exception " +ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the use of `int k = pst.executeUpdate();`

Your query isn't an update statement, so it doesn't make sense to execute an update, it is likely that this will ALWAYS return `0`, as no rows where updated.

Instead use `executeQuery`, which returns a `ResultSet`, which can use to determine if there are any rows matching your query, for example

```
try{
    //System.out.println("iam in first line");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,passsword)) {
        String userName = ex.getUserName();
        String password = ex.getPassword();
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from employee where username = ? and password = ? "); `after this line control is not there`
        pst.setString(1, userName);
        pst.setString(2, password);
        try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.hasNext()) {
                // Registered
            } else {
                // Unregistered
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception tex)
{
    tex.printStackTrace();
    //System.out.println("hey there is an exception " +ex);
}
```

You may want to take a closer look at the [JDBC(TM) Database Access trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Comment: I have tried executeQuery() and that is returning resultset but then y control is not coming to pst.setString(1, userName)

Comment: PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from employee where username = ? and password = ? ");
  pst.setString(1, userName);
  pst.setString(2, password);
  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  boolean  more = rs.next();
       
        if(!more)
        {
         System.out.println("you are not a registered user!");
         ex.setValid(false);
        }

Comment: @HimanshuRawat It doesn't need to.  Either the query is going to return a `ResultSet` with rows or a empty `ResultSet`, hence the use of `if (rs.hasNext())`.

Comment: error is this 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password =himanshu' at line 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)

Comment: Then there is problem with your query.  Are the column names correct for the `employee` table? It almost looks like you've used String concatenation instead of the `PreparedStatement`

Comment: can you please tell how to make the correct query bcz the same query i am writing over workbench is working

Comment: I've been steering at this query for like half an hour and I can't see anything immediately wrong with it, you might try `"Select * from employee where username=? and password=?"` (note the removal of the spaces around the `?` including the trailing space at the end)

Comment: i tried with the solution you provided but the exception still persists as

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password =himanshu' at line 1

Comment: PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from employee where username=? and password=?");
after this line control coming here

Comment: System.out.println("Welcome " + firstName);
             ex.setFirstName(firstName);
             ex.setLastName(lastName);
             ex.setValid(true);

Comment: Have you tried `select * from employee where username=?` and leaving the password off for the moment?

Comment: i  Tried but problem still there !

Comment: `select * from \`employee\` where \`username\`=? and \`password\`=?` ... ?

Comment: By everything I know, the query should be working. What I suggest is you delete this question and ask a new question about why the query (with the code) is causing the exception

Comment: still there ? 
i think this could be the compatibilty problem of sql server

Comment: I can't see why you'd be getting `'password =himanshu'` in your exception message when you're using a prepared statement. Are you sure the code you've posted is the code you are using?